# mysql query strategy to find keyword matches

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if the question is dumb. But I have a real problem in doing this in a right way.

I have 1st table, which are `announcements` , where I have `Title, Description`  where users add some announcements.

There is another table, where we have

1 `id, email, keyword1,keyword2,keyword4,keyword5`  where users add up to 5 keywords, and when such keywords would appear in any newly added announcement , I need to send out an email to the email mentioned in this table. So question is, what is the fastest and optimal solution to solve this problem?

Now when an announcement is added I am taking all items in second table, and then for each one I loop and make a query with **Like %keyword1%** statements, and this take long. And it will take too much when I will have 20.000 entries for example.

So  what would be the best way ? Maybe one query which will list

```
title,keyword,email ??
```

Comment: How big is your announcement description? And do you have the flexibility to handle this outside SQL?

Comment: He probably already handles that outside of SQL since he's matching LIKE %keyword% which is not doable in pure SQL using keywords from other columns as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in an opposite way. Do not match keywords against your announcements, but match announcements against your table with users+keywords.

When you add a new announcement, build a special string with your new query, which will directly match keywords in `users` table. For example, lets assume that your added announcement is this:

```
New product! (this is title)
We have added new product, check it out!
```

Now take all words from your announcement:

```
New product We have added check it out
```

and build a query WHERE clause:

```
keyword1 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out") OR 
keyword1 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out") OR 
keyword2 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out") OR 
keyword3 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out") OR 
keyword4 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out") OR 
keyword5 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out")
```

Finally make the whole query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE 
   keyword1 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out") OR 
   keyword2 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out") OR 
   keyword3 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out") OR 
   keyword4 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out") OR 
   keyword5 IN ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out")
```

Make sure you have INDEX on your keyword1,2,3,4,5 columns. This query will be VERY fast and will return you just the users which match your words from newly added announcement.

Just make sure that the entire query string is not longer than your max packet size (which is usually like 8MB or so)

Comment: Very interesting idea. I would check it out.

Comment: I think there should be a possibilty to use SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
    ->     AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Comment: using MATCH() AGAINST() works only if you have the keywords as string. It cannot match against column. That's a limitation of MySQL

Comment: What is your expected maximum size of announcement text? Can it be bigger than say 1 MB? What is data size of 'title' and 'description' in your announcements table? If that is type `TEXT` then maximum size is 64KB only anyway, so I see no problem here.

Comment: type is TEXT you are right. So I will go forward with it, if we will experience some problems I will let you know ;) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Searching by using query like operation is slow , but there are lot of technologies which you can use like :-

1. Apache solr
2. Egothor
3. Nutch
4. Lucene
5. Oxyus , etc.

These tools will give best performance.

**Otherwise you can use query optimization also :-**

Users like a "quick search", and for usability I think this works best matching anywhere in the string -- therefore a LIKE '%first_name%' condition.

I don't bother to separate fields & clauses out for the "quick search". (For a full-weight search form I have separate inputs for each field the user can search on.) But quick search is a simple UI.

I do it case-insensitive. If it's not your DB's default, you can use a lower() function on the string before matching.

For input 'Robin':

```
select * from members 
where fullname like '%Robin%' or email like '%Robin%'
```

Or, like I do in FireBird to force case-insensitivity:

```
select * from members 
where lower(fullname) like '%robin%' or lower(email) like '%robin%'
```

This would match all combination of name i.e

1. Robin Xyx

   2. robin abc
   3. abc robin
   4. ac.robin@gmail.com and so on

You can keep the first and lastname fields separate, if you want.. my designs prefer to keep them together, since I mainly just use the fullname for display purposes & don't care as to distinctions.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

It makes it a little more difficult because the keywords are arrayed on the table.  I would recommend considering having those on another table and I believe it will help you with the query.

I think something like this will work out

```
select * from users u
inner join announcement a on instr(a.description, u.keyword1) > 0

union

select * from users u
inner join announcement a on instr(a.description, u.keyword2) > 0

union

select * from users u
inner join announcement a on instr(a.description, u.keyword3) > 0
```

You will have to keep adding unions in for each keyword.  Here is a [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d874/1/0) I put together for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a table with 5 columns for the keywords, I would use instead something like:

```
table announcement: announcement_id, title, description
table user: user_id, email
table keyword: keyword_id, keywordvalue
table user_keyword: user_id, keyword_id
```

Then it will be easier to run a query to find all keywords related to a user.

Comment: and how would it be easier? you still end up with keywords in some columns and you cannot use MATCH()

Comment: It would be easier because, given the example, the query would be:  

`select  
 u.user_id  
from  
 user u, user_keyword uk, keyword k  
where  
 u.user_id=uk.user_id and  
 uk.keyword_id = k.keyword_id and  
 k.keywordvalue in ("New","product","We","have","added","check","it", "out")`  
  
and sql needs to parse only a single "in" list and not "or" conditions.

Comment: You can also have an extra table to separate keywords (you can do this at the time
the announcement is saved):  

`table announcementKW: announcementKW_id, announcement_id, word`  
 
an then your query will not need "in":  

`select distinct
 u.user_id, akw.id_announcement
from
 user u, user_keyword uk, keyword k, announcementKW akw  
where
 u.user_id=uk.user_id and
 uk.keyword_id = k.keyword_id and
 k.keywordvalue = akw.word`
  
If worried about performance, delete the rows in announcementKW after sending your notifications.